# linux epson driver fast printing

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

Windows epson inkjet printer driver offers "fast printing" option that provides 1.5-2x faster printing without noticeable quality loss (by printing in a bi-directional manner, printing head prints while it travels forth and back).

Is there a way I could achieve this mode in Linux (Ubuntu)?

Neither CUPS, nor GUI offer such an option.

Comment: Which printer do you use and did you install a proprietary driver?

Comment: We use Epson inkjet L310 and L800 in our photo-kiosks
Driver comes from download.ebz.epson.net.
I believe it is an official source of linux drivers for Epson

Comment: If you installed that driver, you should be able to choose "Draft" as a quality option. There are lot's of other settings.

Comment: Epson has great tech support, you can call the toll free number.

Comment: same problem here, L805 printer with ESC/P-R driver in CUPS